# Why Select faster than Set statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

i did 2 basic tests

**1-**

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[SetLoop]
As Begin 
declare @counter int = 0 ,@a int,@b int,@c int,@d int,@e int
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
        set @a=1
        set @b=2
        set @c=3
        set @d=4
        set @e=5
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    End
End
```

---

```
create procedure SelectLoop
As Begin 
declare @counter int =0 ,@a int,@b int,@c int,@d int,@e int
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
        select @a=1, @b=2, @c=3, @d=4, @e=5,@counter = @counter + 1
    End
End
```

---

```
    var setTimes = new List<double>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        dataContext.SetLoop();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        setTimes.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    var selectTimes = new List<double>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        dataContext.SelectLoop();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        selectTimes.Add(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    var setAverage = setTimes.Sum() / setTimes.Count;
    var selectAverage = selectTimes.Sum()/selectTimes.Count;
```

---

**Results**

```
setAverage : 2418.44
selectAverage : 1037.52

setAverage : 2513.8
selectAverage : 1025.98

setAverage : 2496.52
selectAverage : 996.36
```

results mean Select faster than Set by `one and half` time exactly by `142.78%`

---

**2-**

```
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
        select @a=1
        select @b=2
        select @c=3
        select @d=4
        select @e=5
        select @counter = @counter + 1
    End
```

---

```
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
        set @a=1
        set @b=2
        set @c=3
        set @d=4
        set @e=5
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    End
```

---

**Results**

```
setAverage : 2518.58
selectAverage : 2504.44

setAverage : 2474.5
selectAverage : 2529.48

setAverage : 2511.22
selectAverage : 2514.04
```

results means they are the same

that's mean if you need to set one variable prefer to use `Select` cuz in the future if 
you want to set another one just `,@w=3` will be added but 
if you want to set more than one variable defiantly you need to use `Select` 
it's easier to write, faster to be executed

But I was wondering why `Select` Faster than `Set` in the first test?

Comment: I would suggest to run similar test but for just one variable , this way you'll have only one `select` and one `set` statement in the loop.

Comment: ok i will do it and update the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not (at least in the example you currently have), you are running 6 SET statements and a single SELECT statement for each iteration of the loop, therefore, I would expect the SELECT to be faster.

I would suggest comparing like for like;

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SelectLoop]
As Begin 
declare @counter int = 0
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
        select @counter = @counter + 1
    End
End

CREATE Procedure [dbo].[SetLoop]
As Begin 
declare @counter int = 0
    While @counter < 1000000
    Begin
       set @counter = @counter + 1
    End
End
```

This will give a more accurate indication as to whether there are differences.

Comment: You are still performing 2 SET operations, compared to a SINGLE select.